# Execution build failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'

Tags: flutter

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
```

> Error:
> Attribute receiver#com.razorpay.RzpTokenReceiver@exported value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:133:13-37 is also present at [com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.34] AndroidManifest.xml:44:13-36 value=(true).
>
> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:exported"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.
>
> C:\Users\kumar\Desktop\Emart_V2.1_Source_Code\apps\eMart_Customer\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:130:13-36
>
> Error: Attribute activity#com.razorpay.CheckoutActivity@exported value=(true) from AndroidManifest.xml:130:13-36 is also present at [com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.34] AndroidManifest.xml:54:13-37 value=(false).
>
> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:exported"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
>
> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 4m 54s
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Please help me I'm new in this field

Comment: It might not be a good idea to post errors with explicit classes com.yourcompanyname.ClassName. Anyway, you should post some relevant code as the build failing message already give you suggestions to fix the issue (add 'tools:replace="android:exported"') or get more insights (Run with --scan to get full insights.)